# Differing axioms for Stiefel-Whitney class

Tags: algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

In Milnor and Stasheff, it is taken as part of the first axiom that all Stiefel-Whitney classes of a bundle vanish in dimensions greater than the rank of the bundle.  However, in other sources this is omitted.  The wikipedia article makes it seem like this is actually a result of the axioms.  Is there a simple proof of this (the axioms I am using are those listed here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel%E2%80%93Whitney_class#Axioms)?

Answer (score 2):

It is certainly both of constructions of the Stiefel-Whitney classes that I know. The construction via the Thom Isomorphism and the Steenrod operations clearly must vanish seeing as the Thom class of the bundle will be in a dimension that is killed by the Steenrod Operation because of instability.

For the construction via universal bundles you look at the universal rank $k$-bundle $\gamma_k$, it has $w_n(\gamma_k)=0$  simply by looking at the cohomology of $BO(k)$, there isn't a polynomial generator in that dimension. The above observation coupled with naturality should give the result, but i don't know if that should count as following from the axioms.

I can flesh this out a bit later if you like.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I am wondering though if there is a more direct proof from the axioms (instead of going through a construction and proving uniqueness).

Comment: I understand completely. Hopefully, someone will come by with an answer.

Comment: Also, it should be pointed out that it could be a mistake in the wikipedia entry...